# TypeError: Cannot read property 'memberCount' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

today i had a error with my bot when i was running it, i was trying to implement the *fancy* activity of Watching over #

but i ran into some issues

here is the code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

const { token, prefix} = require('./config.json');

const infernoGuild = client.guilds.resolve('724848757589409854')
const guildMemberCount = infernoGuild.memberCount;

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity(`over ${guildMemberCount}`, {type: 'WATCHING'})
  .then(presence => console.log(`Activity set to ${presence.activities[0].name}`))
  .catch(console.error);
})

client.on('ready', async message => {
  let args 
})

client.login(token)
```

and here is the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'memberCount' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sameerabdullah/Desktop/yousef/InfernoAPI/server.js:7:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

i couldn't find any answer to this on the internet

***sorry for my bad english***

Comment: why are you using resolve? and are you on v11 or v12?

Comment: v12, also because there isn't a find or get function

Comment: in v12 you have to use .cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const infernoGuild = client.guilds.cache.get("724848757589409854");
if (!infernoGuild) return console.error(`The Guild ID is invalid.`);

client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setActivity(`over ${infernoGuild.memberCount}`, {type: "WATCHING"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use: const infernoGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('724848757589409854')

Comment: Nope, it now says undefined and not null

Comment: const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
 did you forgot that? because Discord needs to be defined when you want to use "Discord.Client"
const client = new Discord.Client();

Comment: you have to add it

Comment: Bro, i have it -_-

Comment: do console.log(infernoGuild) after the infernoGuild line and start again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218349/discussion-between-nicohd105-and-galaksy).